# Google Analytics, Outbound Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-log, outbound

Having an Issue With recording outbound link events in my google analytics. This is such a simple task I cannot understand where it can go wrong. Can any one notice any issues with my code. The google functions are being executed upon my onclick events, The issue is that no event is being logged on my google analytics dashboard In Behaviour > Events > Overview

**google_analytics.php**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-86854644-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');


 var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  alert(url);
     ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
       'transport': 'beacon',
       'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
     });
}



function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event,
    transport: 'beacon'
  });
}

</script>
```

**Click Event**

```
onclick=\"handleOutboundLinkClicks(this);\"
```

**header.php**

```
include_once("/includes/google_analytics.php");
```

Comment: I think the browser is redirecting the user to the link before tracking is done. You have to stop browser's action of opening the link with [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), so your code on `hitCallback` is actually called after the event is sent.

Comment: I thought this may have been the case two. I have tried the following be still no log of the call back           onclick=\"trackOutboundLink('$hreflink',event);\"                                                   var trackOutboundLink = function(url,event) {
  alert(event);
  event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For the help, I agree that Event Listeners are a better approach especially with multiple event but my initial function and click event worked, Turns out it just took some time for google analytics to present it on my dashboard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `event` as parameter, but it's not `this`. There's no such thing as `'$hreflink'`. Avoid using the onclick! (See below.)

When you send `this`, you're sending the element itself (the `<a>` element in your case). So in your case I would do something like in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz7nzrq1/1/):

```
theAnchor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // avoid browser from following the href
    event.preventDefault();

    // call google analytics, and on hitCallback, follow the url:
    document.location = this.href; // `this` is the own element
});
```

---

## Avoid using the `onclick` attribute!

Don't mix HTML and JavaScript; don't use the `onclick` attribute (and similars). They are not good for event management and, as your application grows, they get more difficult to maintain.

That said, use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add events to an element (as seen in the examples above).

Comment: Sounds Possible, I am away from my PC ATM, will try as soon as back. BTW '$hreflink' is the link of the external page that is being navigated to, its a php var. Will let you know if Event Listener works. THANKS